# Error implementacion arboles binarios java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando implementar Arboles binarios en java pero me da un error que no entiendo, me podrían ayudar?

Existe la interfaz y también el nodo con sus método, pero cuando implemento esta ultima clase me sale un error exactamente en esta linea **Class Linked.... LinkedBinaryTree.class** justo debajo del `try` el cual es

> error: not a statement LinkedBinaryTree 1bt= new LinkedBinaryTree();

y las siguientes dos lineas me dice que les falta ";" pero como se evidencia no es verdad

```
 public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTree<T>{

    BinaryTreeNode<T> root;

    static Method visit;
    static Method theAdd1;
    static Method theOutput;
    static int count;

    static{
        try{
            Class<LinkedBinaryTree> 1bt =  LinkedBinaryTree.class;
            theAdd1 = 1bt.getMethod("add1", BinaryTreeNode.class);
            theOutput = 1bt.getMethod("output",BinaryTreeNode.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //exception not possible
        }
    }
```

Comment: No veo la línea que dices `LinkedBinaryTree 1bt= new LinkedBinaryTree();`

Comment: Es la que esta debajo de try, la pagina no me dejaba poner <> @EvgeniEnchev

Comment: Pero debajo del try no tienes `new LinkedBinaryTree()`, lo que tienes es `LinkedBinaryTree.class`, no hay **new**. No me cuadra.

Comment: Las variables no pueden empezar por numero.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes declarar una variable donde el nombre comienze con un numero:

```
1bt =  LinkedBinaryTree.class; // -> nombre de variable 1bt no es correcta.
```

Tendras que cambiar el nombre de la variable a que comienze con una letra.